# Raster to TIN error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, raster-conversion, error-999999, tin

I have a big raster file (6,5gb) that I am trying to convert it to TIN format.

What happens is that after 15-25 min of processing I get this error message [image: raster_to_tin_error]

Can someone tell me how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

A TIN in ArcGIS is limited to 15-20 million nodes so your TIN may be hitting that limit.   If you think that is the case you could convert the raster to points and then feed those points into an ArcGIS Terrain which does not have those node limitations.

What you hope to gain by doing a raster to TIN conversion is unclear.